# how to construct a for statement that determines the root mean square from a list of data (numeric data) written in an Octave

Tags: math, octave, octave-gui

[image]

So I am being asked on doing this simple problem, I know how to code in C/C++, and Java, but this is very different from those languages, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Octave conveniently works on 'vectorised' data.

E.g. if you have an array `x = [1,2,3,4,5]`

then you can

- square all elements using the `.^` operator (a synonym for the [`power`](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Arithmetic-Ops.html#index-power) function)
- divide all elements in the array by [dividing](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Arithmetic-Ops.html#index-rdivide) with a single scalar, which will be broadcasted to all elements in the array (also see [list of arithmetic operators](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Arithmetic-Ops.html) )

There exists a [`sum`](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Sums-and-Products.html#index-sum) function which sums over arrays.

For the square root you can use [`sqrt`](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Exponents-and-Logarithms.html#index-sqrt) (or simply exponentiate using a power of 0.5)

See the [octave manual](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/index.html) for more details.